# React 16: Call children's function from parent when using hooks and functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to call children's function in their parent component. How should I do it? Previous in React 15, I can use refs to call children's function. But have no idea how to do it with hooks and functional component.

```
function Child(props) {
    function validate() {
        // to validate this component
    }

    return (
        <>Some code here</>
    )
}


function Parent(props) {
    const refs = useRef([]);
    const someData = [1,2,3,4,5];

    function validateChildren() {
        refs.current.forEach(child => {
            child.current.validate(); // throw error!! can not get validate function
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={validateChildren}>Validate</button>
            {
                someData.map((data, index) => {
                    return <Child ref={ins => refs.current[index] = ins} />
                })
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

My actual requirement is:
 1. There are multiple tabs which can be added, delete base on user's behaviour 
 2. Click a button in the parent of tabs to trigger validate
 3. All the tabs need to validate itself, show error message in their tabs and return a validate message

Comment: Can you add something about the exact requirement?

Comment: Hi Clark, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `useImperativeHandle` with [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle),

> **useImperativeHandle** customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref. As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases. **useImperativeHandle** should be used with **forwardRef**

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

    //validate will be available to parent component using ref
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      validate() {
        // to validate this component
        console.log("I'm clicked");
      }
    }));

    return (
        <>Some code here</>
    )
})
```

In the parent compoennt you can access child function as,

```
function validateChildren() {
   refs.current.forEach(child => {
      child.validate(); // you can access child method here 
   });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a1mlqw)

Comment: thanks for this answer. I'm using it in React Native. Could you explain a little more what's happening with the instance when you pass the ref to the child in this line: ref={ins => refs.current[index] = ins}

Comment: Thanks, but what about this statement?
"As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases"
What is the best practice in this case? Have a `counter` in Parent, pass it down to Child and use a `usePrevious` logic in child to trigger the `validate` method? 
Isn't that ugly and causes an extra re-render of Parent? Is there another best practice?