# Can't access child function from parent function with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I need to call a function in a child component from a parent component with React Hooks.

I was trying to adapt this question to my use case [React 16: Call children's function from parent when using hooks and functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037115/react-16-call-childrens-function-from-parent-when-using-hooks-and-functional-c)
 but I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: childRef.childFunction is not a function
```

My parent component is like this:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Child from './child'

function Parent() {
    const parentRef = useRef()
    const childRef = useRef()

    const callChildFunction = () => {
        childRef.current(childRef.childFunction())
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (parentRef && childRef) {
            callChildFunction();
        }
    }, [parentRef, childRef])

    return (
        <div ref={parentRef} className="parentContainer">
            PARENT
            <Child ref={childRef}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Parent;
```

My child component is like this:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const Child = forwardRef(({ref}) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        childFunction() {
            console.log("CHILD FUNCTION")
        }
      })); 

    return (
        <div className="childContainer">
            CHILD
        </div>
    );
})

export default Child;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this hook. But from the docs `imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases`. Why not elevate the state to the parent. or use redux or context hooks to pass values and functions between components?

Comment: `childRef.current(childRef.childFunction())` - is this intentional? shouldn't you be calling `childRef.current.childFunction()` directly?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is I have a child component that uses data from a context, and also takes data as an input, but the context is not refreshing in the child component when the context is reset from the parent - but the use case is very particular

Comment: I tried both childRef.current(childRef.childFunction()) and childRef.current.childFunction() - both produce the same error for me. I think I used the first one coz I was adapting the function from the example and they were using a forEach over an array of refs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem

```
    childRef.current(childRef.childFunction())
```

`childRef.current` isn't a function. Also `childRef.childFunction()` is run first, which also isn't a function.

`childRef.current.childFunction` should be a function, try `childRef.current.childFunction()` instead of `childRef.current(childRef.childFunction())`

---

From the docs on `useImperativeHandle` check out the usage of `inputRef.current.focus()`:

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} ... />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

In this example, a parent component that renders `<FancyInput ref={inputRef} />` would be able to call `inputRef.current.focus()`.

Edit based on comment for future visitors:

```
const Child = forwardRef(({ref}) => {
```

should be

```
const child = forwardRef(({}, ref) => {
```

Comment: I had also mixed up refs and props. The ref isn't a prop so I had to put forwardRef(({}, ref) => { etc...

Comment: Thanks, updated answer for that for future viewers.

Comment: I have a question about how the parent would be able to call inputRef.current.focus()? How would you do that?

Comment: I don't use this methodology anymore. If I need something to run in my child, I either modify a prop that is inbound or do something to make useEffect run. I think it's kind of an anti pattern.