# Trigger child function from parent component using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have some action buttons in parent components. On click of one of such buttons, I would like to trigger a function in the child component. Currently, I am trying to implement it using useRef hook. But the solution seems tedious and also gives me warning:

[image]

My current code looks like:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
const ParentComponent = ({...props})=> {
const myRef = useRef();
const onClickFunction = () => {
        if(myRef.current) {
            myRef.current.childFunction();
        }
    }
return (
<ChildComponent ref = {myRef}/>
);
}
```

Child component

```
const ChildComponent = (({}, ref,{  actionButtons, ...props}) => {
const [childDataApi, setChildDataApi] = useState(null);

const childFunction = () => {
       //update childDataApi and pass it to parent
        console.log("inside refreshEntireGrid");
    }
});
```

Firstly, is there a better solution then trying to trigger childFunction from parent ? For this I am following this solution:
[Can't access child function from parent function with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346719/cant-access-child-function-from-parent-function-with-react-hooks)
I tried adding forward ref but that threw error as well.
[image]

I also found out that lifting the state up could be another solution as well. But I am not able to understand how to apply that solution in my case. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: The solution you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346719/cant-access-child-function-from-parent-function-with-react-hooks) to is the correct solution for forwarding a ref to a child component and imperatively invoking a function. What isn't working for you in this implementation? Can you update your question to include what you tried and what the issue/error is?

Comment: Sure! I added how I used forwardRef following that solution link and the warning it gave me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning says you were using `forwardRef` so with your snippet `const ChildComponent = (({}, ref, { actionButtons, ...props }) => { .... }` I'll assume this is a typo in your question and you were actually doing `const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef(({}, ref,{ actionButtons, ...props }) => { .... })`.

The issue here, and the warning message points this out, is that you are passing a third argument to `forwardRef` when it only consumes two. It seems you destructure ***nothing*** from the first `props` argument. From what I can tell you should replace the first argument with the third where it looks like you are doing some props destructuring.

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef(({ actionButtons, ...props }, ref) => { .... }
```

From here you should implement the `useImperativeHandle` hook to expose out the function from the child.

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef(({ actionButtons, ...props }, ref) => {
  const [childDataApi, setChildDataApi] = useState(null);
  
  const childFunction = () => {
    // update childDataApi and pass it to parent
    console.log("inside refreshEntireGrid");
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    childFunction
  }));

  ...

  return ( ... );
});
```

In the parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
  const myRef = useRef();

  const onClickFunction = () => {
    myRef.current?.childFunction();
  }

  return (
    <ChildComponent ref={myRef}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this solution worked. I was using useImperativeHandle incorrectly.

Comment: 10 upvotes!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Something else you can try is to pass a prop to the child to indicate that the button has been clicked and use `useEffect` in the child component to do something when that value changes.

```
const Child = props => {
  useEffect(() => TriggeredFunc(), [props.buttonClicked]);

  const TriggeredFunc = () => {
    ...
  }

  return '...';
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(0);

  const onClick = e => {
    setButtonClicked(buttonClicked++);
  }

  return <>
    <button onClick={onClick}>My Button</button>
    <Child buttonClicked={buttonClicked} />;
  </>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to call a child component's function from its parent is with  the **useRef** hook

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childFunc = React.useRef(null)

  return (
    <>
      <Child childFunc={childFunc} />
      <button onClick={() => childFunc.current()}>Click me</button>
    </>
  )
}

const Child = ({ childFunc }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    childFunc.current = alertUser
  }, [childFunc.current])

  function alertUser() {
    alert('You clicked!')
  }

  return null
}

render(<Parent />)
```