# How to trigger children's functions via parent's button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component called `SettingsPage`, and on that page, there could be one of several different child components depending on what `tab` is.

Here's the simplified example of my current page:

```js
const SettingsPage = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState('user');

  return (
    <div className="settings-page">
      <div className="content">
        {tab === 'user' && <UserSettings />}
        {tab === 'feed' && <FeedSettings />}
        {tab === 'privacy' && <PrivacySettings />}
      </div>
      <footer>
        { /* how do I trigger onSave function of the child components? */ }
        <button className="btn btn-save">Save</button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

/* userSettings.jsx */
const UserSettings = () => {
  const onSave = () => console.log('user settings saved');
  return (
    <div>User Settings</div>
  )
};

/* feedSettings.jsx */
const FeedSettings = () => {
  const onSave = () => console.log('feed settings saved');
  return (
    <div>Feed Settings</div>
  )
};

/* privacySettings.jsx */
const PrivacySettings = () => {
  const onSave = () => console.log('privacy settings saved');
  return (
    <div>Privacy Settings</div>
  )
};
```

In the footer of the parent component, I have a save button, that I want it upon clicking, the corresponding child component's `onSave` function should be triggered. I don't want to put the save logic in the parent component since all changes are happening in the child component.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Lift the save logic out of the components, and then you can call when you like.  Eg.  Make a `saveFeed` function, and then assign to your button, and you can then also call in parent.

Comment: Yeah, the proper way is to lift your state up - Otherwise, you can use the `useImperativeHandle()` - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642839/5648954)

Comment: Strongly echoing these comments, the accepted answer works, but it’s not the “easy” way to do react. It’s the hard way, it’s upside down-react. Parents shouldn’t “trigger” functions in children (in the majority of cases). If you start putting state in these child components, it’ll get harder and harder. An alternative to lifting all things up to the parent is to just move the button JSX into each of the children. Wrapping your mind around the way react wants you to write code is both hard and critical to writing good react code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define a Forwarded Ref for Each Child Component.
2. Use useImperativeHandle in Child Components.
3. Manage Refs in the Parent Component.

UserSettings.js:

```
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';

const UserSettings = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const onSave = () => console.log('user settings saved');
  
  // This will expose the onSave method to the parent component via ref
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    onSave
  }));

  return <div>User Settings</div>;
});
```

SettingsPage.js:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import UserSettings from './UserSettings'; // Import your components
import FeedSettings from './FeedSettings';
import PrivacySettings from './PrivacySettings';

const SettingsPage = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState('user');
  const activeComponentRef = useRef(null);

  const onSaveClick = () => {
    if (activeComponentRef.current) {
      activeComponentRef.current.onSave();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="settings-page">
      <div className="content">
        {tab === 'user' && <UserSettings ref={activeComponentRef} />}
        {tab === 'feed' && <FeedSettings ref={activeComponentRef} />}
        {tab === 'privacy' && <PrivacySettings ref={activeComponentRef} />}
      </div>
      <footer>
        <button className="btn btn-save" onClick={onSaveClick}>Save</button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Although the syntax is a little bit obscure but I guess it's just a React thing.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I was able to help. Haha react is fun when it comes to syntax.